# CMake Error at cmake/modules/AddLLVM.cmake:83 (add_executable)

Tags: cmake, llvm-clang

I am trying build LLVMLinux project and follow this link http://llvm.linuxfoundation.org/index.php/Nexus_7, but I got following problems after I ran **make all** or just build the clang, it shows that

CMake Error at cmake/modules/AddLLVM.cmake:83 (add_executable):
      add_executable cannot create target "llvm-symbolizer" because another
      target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is an
      executable created in source directory
      "/Volumes/macdat/scratch/LLVMLinux/llvmlinux/toolchain/clang/src/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/utils/llvm-symbolizer".
      See documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      cmake/modules/AddLLVM.cmake:99 (add_llvm_executable)
      tools/llvm-symbolizer/CMakeLists.txt:11 (add_llvm_tool)

```
CMake Error at cmake/modules/LLVM-Config.cmake:58 (target_link_libraries):
  Attempt to add link library "LLVMDebugInfo" to target "llvm-symbolizer"
  which is not built in this directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/LLVM-Config.cmake:50 (explicit_llvm_config)
  cmake/modules/AddLLVM.cmake:86 (llvm_config)
  cmake/modules/AddLLVM.cmake:99 (add_llvm_executable)
  tools/llvm-symbolizer/CMakeLists.txt:11 (add_llvm_tool)


CMake Error at cmake/modules/LLVM-Config.cmake:58 (target_link_libraries):
  Attempt to add link library "LLVMObject" to target "llvm-symbolizer" which
  is not built in this directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/LLVM-Config.cmake:50 (explicit_llvm_config)
  cmake/modules/AddLLVM.cmake:86 (llvm_config)
  cmake/modules/AddLLVM.cmake:99 (add_llvm_executable)
  tools/llvm-symbolizer/CMakeLists.txt:11 (add_llvm_tool)


CMake Error at cmake/modules/LLVM-Config.cmake:58 (target_link_libraries):
  Attempt to add link library "LLVMSupport" to target "llvm-symbolizer" which
  is not built in this directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/LLVM-Config.cmake:50 (explicit_llvm_config)
  cmake/modules/AddLLVM.cmake:86 (llvm_config)
  cmake/modules/AddLLVM.cmake:99 (add_llvm_executable)
  tools/llvm-symbolizer/CMakeLists.txt:11 (add_llvm_tool)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Volumes/macdat/scratch/LLVMLinux/llvmlinux/toolchain/clang/build/llvm/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Volumes/macdat/scratch/LLVMLinux/llvmlinux/toolchain/clang/build/llvm/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [/Volumes/macdat/scratch/LLVMLinux/llvmlinux/toolchain/clang/state/llvm-configure] Error 1
```

Anybody has also encountered this? And what is problem here? Can anybody give hints how to solve it?

Thanks in advance